# Push above view up while animating slide up another view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have following view inside my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <!-- some child views here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <!-- some other child views here -->

    </LinearLayout>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

The wrapper RelativeLayout is aligned to bottom of its parent. And initialy footer view is not displayed (View.GONE). When header view is tapped, then footer should be shown to user with slide up animation from bottom of screen and when user taps again footer should be slide down to bottom. When i start an slide up animation on footer view, it does not push header view simultaneously with animation. If i first set footer view visibility to View.INVISIBLE first and then start animation, header view is pushed up immediately (not together with animation or footer view), and footer view comes with animation.

Here is the code to call animation

```
footer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide_up_from_bottom);
animation.setDuration(animDuration);
footer.startAnimation(animation);
footer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, animDuration);
```

and this is the animation file content:

How can i make this animation to push header view, while footer view sliding up?

Hope i made myself clear. All i want is both views moves up/down together.

If i apply animation to wrapper view then it slides up from bottom (not from current location).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your header to push along with footer animation, you can do it manually as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private LinearLayout header,footer;
private RelativeLayout wrapper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    header = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
    footer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer);
    wrapper = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

    header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(footer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){             
                int footerHeight = footer.getMeasuredHeight();
                float initialWrapperY = wrapper.getY();                 
                ObjectAnimator oa=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(wrapper, "y", initialWrapperY,initialWrapperY+footerHeight);
                oa.setDuration(400);
                oa.start();
                oa.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    public void onAnimationEnd(android.animation.Animator animation) {
                        footer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    };
                });
            }
            else{                   
                final float initialWrapperY = wrapper.getY();           
                footer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                wrapper.setY(initialWrapperY);
                ViewTreeObserver vto=wrapper.getViewTreeObserver();
                vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {                     
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreDraw() {
                        wrapper.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                        final int footerHeight = footer.getMeasuredHeight();                            
                        ObjectAnimator oa=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(wrapper, "y", initialWrapperY,(initialWrapperY-footerHeight));
                        oa.setDuration(400);
                        oa.start();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }               
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: I've been trying to do this for hours. Your answer works perfectly, thanks a lot !